# Why elements in strings(dictionary) are changing position automatically?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

library version...
python: 3.7.4.final.0
pandas: 1.0.0
numpy : 1.18.1

```
strings = {'one','two','three','four'} 
stri = ["one",'two','three','four']     
print("strings={} \n stri={}".format(strings, stri))   

#elements in strings changes position!!!   output:    strings={'four', 'two', 'three', 'one'} 
#elements in stri remains in same order!!!   output:  stri=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

why elements in strings are changing the order?

Comment: It's not a dictionary, it's a `set` and `set`s are unordered unlike `list`s.

Answer (score 1):

Sets are unordered collections. They do not have order, that is why you cannot do something like this:

```
mySet[0]
```

Comment: @Selcuk check my updated answer.. I accidentally referred to it as a dictionary but I meant set